# Limit user.getWeeklyAlbumChart from Last.fm API

Tags: api, limit, last.fm

Is there any way to limit the amount of albums returned using user.getWeeklyAlbumChart and the Last.fm API? Unfortunately "limit" doesn't seem to be an acceptable parameter.

http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getWeeklyAlbumChart

However, I was able to limit the weekly *artist* chart using the "limit" parameter, even though "limit" apparently isn't an accepted parameter for this method either.

http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getWeeklyArtistChart

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getWeeklyAlbumChart), there is no way to do that using Last.fm API, but you can limit the amount of returned albums when you call your function. Can you provide some code for example?

Comment: Thanks, but don't worry about it. I'm able to limit the amount of albums using a for loop but I was hoping to use the limit parameter to make the API call less costly.